# Paerser Error when loading C# ASP.NET website hosted on GoDaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am hosting a website with GoDaddy, recently I started getting errors when trying to load the site.
I am publishing the site to file system and then loading the site to the right folder in my hosting account. The site worked before but I had to update and how I'm getting this error, the site works fine in my IIS setup I use for testing sites.

```
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was "D:\Hosting\13634184\html\{domain-name}.com\bin\roslyn\csc.exe" /shared /keepalive:"10" /noconfig  /fullpaths @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\{domain-name}.com\748bda03\4edc4877\ux22cjxn.cmdline".

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="{project-name}._Default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">


Source File: /{domain-name}.com/default.aspx    Line: 1
```

The last part of the Parser Error Message "\ux22cjxn.cmdline" changes pretty much every time the site is loaded

Comment: Include the actual text of your error in your question, not as an image. It's hard to search images and Imgur is down now anyways.

Comment: Edited the original post to use text instead of an image.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I had the trust level set, but the problem was the

```
    <system.codedom>
       <!-- All is removed between the 2 tags-->
    </system.codedom>
```

Removing the code from here fixed the problem.